# How can I handle a custom HTTP exception?

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I created an exception called invalid balance, and I'm using like the following. My output result status is 500. How can I change this status to 400?

```php
try {
    $balance = Wallet::findOrFail()->docs()
        ->sum('amount');

    if ($balance == 0) {
        throw new InvalidBalance();
    }

} catch (QueryException $e) {
    $message = Str::contains($e->getMessage(), 'Deadlock') ? 
        'Server is busy' : $e->getMessage();
    throw new HttpException(400, $message);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Show your InvalidException class and tell where you have put that file.

Comment: Have your `InvalidBalance` exception extend `HttpException` with a code of 400 sent to the parent constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [abort](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#http-exceptions) helper.

```php
if ($balance === 0) 
{
    abort(400, 'Bad Request.');
}
```

Or within the `InvalidBalance` class do the abort there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response()` method and pass the http status code as the second parameter as in [laravel helpers functions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-response)

```
 return response()->json(['message'=>'your message'], 400);
```